# send complex object json to webservice with jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send a json object to webservice in asp.net by $.ajax but I can't retrive a nested object into an array.
Client code:

```
  var fiscaldocument = {

            "datetime": "2013-08-07 17:37:41", "operatorname": "admin", "total": 21800 
            , "fiscallines":
            [
                { "id": 254, "itemid": "3", "amount": 1000, "price": 2832, "description": "ACQUA", "categoryid": 1, "sequence": 0, "type": 1, "categoryname": "BEVANDE", "taxrate": 21000 },
                { "id": 255, "itemid": "3", "amount": 1000, "price": 5024, "description": "ACQUA", "categoryid": 1, "sequence": 0, "type": 1, "categoryname": "BEVANDE", "taxrate": 21000 },

            ],
            "paymentlines":
            [
                {"paymentform":{"id":1,"name":"creditcard"},"total":1800},
                {"paymentform":{"id":2,"name":"cash"},"total":20000}    
            ]
            };

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "webservice.asmx/ExportFiscalDocument",
        data: "{'fiscaldocument':" + JSON.stringify(fiscaldocument) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
        alert("ok");
       }
      });
```

C# code rappresentation of JSON:

```
 public class PaymentForm
    {
        int id { get; set; }
        string name { get; set; }

    }

    public class PaymentLine
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public PaymentForm paymentform { get; set; }
    }

    public class FiscalLine
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int itemid { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int categoryid { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string categoryname { get; set; }
        public int taxrate { get; set; }

    }

    public class FiscalDocument
    {
       public string datetime { get; set; }
       public string operatorname { get; set; }
       public string total { get; set; }
       public List<FiscalLine> fiscallines { get; set; }
       public List<PaymentLine> paymentlines { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string ExportFiscalDocument(FiscalDocument fiscaldocument)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

All values are okay but webservice can't parse data into PaymentForm: fiscaldocument.paymentlines[0].paymentform.id == NULL :-(

[image]

If I pass the array in this way values are ok:

```
[{ "id":1,"name":"creditcard","total":1800},
{ "id":1,"name":"cash","total":2000}]
```

Comment: So you are asking how to change the json for `paymentforms` to array style, like at bottom?

Comment: I would mantain the same structure... :)

"paymentlines":
            [
                {"paymentform":{"id":1,"name":"creditcard"},"total":1800},
                {"paymentform":{"id":2,"name":"cash"},"total":20000}    
            ]
            };

Comment: Don't understand the question?

Comment: My question is: why aspnet can't parse paymentform? is the structure malformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem

```
    public class PaymentForm
    {
        int id { get; set; }
        string name { get; set; }
    }
```

I forgot PUBLIC :-(

```
    public class PaymentForm
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```